# Stay/keep abreast of

Tags: meaning-in-context, ambiguity

Somewhere in my essay it goes as follows:

> There is a shared assumption that English is estranging people from
>   their own language, inclining them to subordinate it to English. Even
>   so commonly held, it seems a flawed assumption in view of the fact that
>   the extent to which most non-natives literally need to learn English
>   barely surpasses the routine, commonplace level of communication, and
>   thus, English cannot keep abreast of their mother languages, in that sense.

My Merriam Webster's Collegiate Dictionary loosely allows this ,at least as far as i see, saying:

> abreast: ... 2. up to a particular standard or level

before narrowing it down:

> especially of knowledge or recent developments.

In hope of finding a similar statement as mine, I came across the following example, flipping through the web pages:

> The Japanese video game industry has certainly failed to stay abreast
>   of its western rivals on the technological front. The Guardian Jul 17,
>   2013

A native speaker said It sounds odd as English is not animated and cannot keep abreast of anything. But the same is true of "industry" which has appeared in the Guardian's example.
Now, could mine too, be correct? and why if not, please?
many thanks in advance

Comment: Keep abreast is not quite right I think. Compare would be better. In any case, that is a horrible sentence. It's missing a word somewhere ('Even so commonly held seems') and it is far too long to read comfortably. Just saying...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sentence is immediately understandable and perfectly clear. The only place that makes the reader really stumble is “Even so commonly held, it seems a flawed assumption…”, which is clumsy and needs a verb in the leading apposition: “Despite being so commonly held, this seems a flawed assumption…”.

With that said, *keep abreast of* does seem ‘off’ somehow. Keeping abreast of something is something that requires two active participants; let’s call them *X* and *Y*.

> *X* is keeping abreast of *Y*

This implies not only that *X* is doing his best to stay ahead of things and moving (or, as Neil says, advancing) forward, but also that *Y* is doing the same thing. *X* and *Y* are in **competition** with each other, and *X* is managing to stay ahead despite *Y* doing his best to catch up and overtake him.

In your sentence, English is *X* and the native language is *Y*. For English to be able to keep/stay abreast of speakers’ native languages, you would have to be implying that the native language is moving or advancing quickly forward, but that English is moving just as fast (or slightly faster) and managing to stay just ahead of the native languages.

The advancement in English can just about work, though it is a bit forced (it is not the English language that advances, but the speakers’ *skills* in using the English language); but when you add the unnaturalness of considering someone’s native language as being competitively advancing somehow, the simile and the idiomaticness breaks down.

As an alternative replacement to Edwin’s *compare*, my first thought was:

> … and thus, English cannot *hold a candle to* their native tongues in that regard.

Answer (score 0):

A video game industry may not literally move but it can certainly *advance* technologically. Thus it's sensible to talk about one such industry keeping (or not keeping) abreast of another when comparing their technological development.

I don't think it's the right metaphor for your argument though. Saying English can't keep abreast of the native language implies the native language is moving forward in some sense, but in your essay you don't provide any such sense.

Comment: I just recognized a point that I wonder if it changes anything: Guardian uses "stay" rather than "keep" which sounds more stationary. So what about putting it like: "English cannot stay abreast of their mother language." Does it palpably change anything, Neil?

Comment: Plus It seems that we can compare "video game" only with "English" and then "their western rivals" only with "their mother language" because of the sides each one takes in their own sentences. and since English is a language that IS BEING LEARNT, advancement CAN be made there.
You know, I've admitted my term hasn't pan out but i really want to appreciate the way a native feels about it and the reason makes him\her reject it.